# ASP.NET: change div content when logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm working with forms and in C#. I have an imagebutton on the index page, when clicked on, you go to the login page. Now I want to make it so that when you are logged in, the imagebutton on the index page is changed to a label "Welcome Username". How Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [LoggedInTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.loggedintemplate.aspx)

```
  <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
  <!-- ImageButton here-->
  </LoggedInTemplate>
  <AnonymousTemplate>
  <!-- Label Here-->
  </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: this is the way to do this with out of the box controls

Answer (score 2):

Use two asp:panels and tricker their visibility according to the state of login.

Comment: I Understand. maybe a bit more on how to tricker their visibility according to thestate of login? Thanks!

Comment: A poor man login signs the session. Maybe with a sha2 of the password+username+salt. And checks on the serverside everytime on page refresh if one can construct a similar hash from the db. Note:this is not a propper way if you a going to make a big and public site.

Answer (score 2):

Use a couple of asp panels, when the user gets logged in, do this:

```
myPanel1.Visible=false;
myPanel2.Visible= true;
```

That would do the trick.